# DAX Formula to find second date - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to get the second approver date from the table

| Approver Level | Approver Date | Approver Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/31/2020 | Approver 1 |
| 2 | 1/4/2021 | Approver 2 |
| 3 | 1/4/2021 | Approver 3 |
| 4 | 1/4/2021 | Approver 4 |
| 5 | 2/4/2021 | Approver 5 |

What I want to achieve is this:

| Approver Level | Approver Date | Approver Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1/4/2021 | Approver 2 |

Any idea

Comment: What you have tried so far? Is your result a table, a column or a measure?

Comment: Measure required it

Comment: And how do you want to display that measure? As a card? Or within a table?

Comment: What's the logic of the result you want to achieve because on 1/4/2021 there are 3 approvers.